# Scrape first occurence

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, scrape

```
<div id="title">
Post Title
</div>

<div id="post">
<a href="some link" id="buton">SOME LINK</a>
<a href="some link" id="buton">SOME OTHER LINK THAT I DONT WANT BUT HAS SAME ID</a>
</div>
```

I am using simple_html_dom to try and scrape some posts from a public website, i can get the title easy enough by just `find->div[id=title]` but i also need the first link from within the post div and because all links in that div have the same id im having a bit of a problem just getting the first one along with its respective title.

I have heard of xPath and would use it if i knew how to but i don't just yet

Answer (score 0):

Even without xpath, given your first example, it seems you should be able to do something trivial like

`find->div[id=post]`

then ask for the children, and from there select the first one.

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
$doc->find('div#post a', 0);
```